# Windows 2019: can't figure out why my drive is full

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization, windows-server-2019

On a Windows 2019 Server **the drive D: is 100% full (500 Gb used)**:

[image]

I'm trying to understand why the disk is full but I can't because both File Explorer and Total Commander reports **no more than 33 Gb used**:

[image]

[image]

It's also strange that WinDirStat reports 100% (500 Gb) used in the start summary, but **only 33 Gb used** after the analysis:

[image]

[image]

**Please note that:**

- I'm logged in as **Administrator**
- I started WinDirStat with **Administrator privileges**
- I tried with both local **Administrator** and Active Directory **Domain Admin**
- I enabled **hidden and system files** in File Explorer and Total Commander
- I ran chkdsk on the D: drive without finding any issue

I found 33 Gb of data. **Where are other 467 Gb?**

Comment: What is the result when you run vssadmin list shadowstorage ?

Comment: @user5870571: No items found that satisfy the query.

Comment: What Services are your running? Do you have automatic backups of the servers content? What are you using Windows Server 2019 for? Please give us some other information. Also were you doing anything out of the ordinary earlier in the week or weeks messing with system settings that may have caused this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could try WizTree (wiztreefree.com), which is similar to WinDirStat but it bypasses the filesystem driver and reads the MFT directly if run as an administrator. It will show space taken by alternate data streams, metadata files ($MFT, $Secure, $BadClus, etc.), and directories you don't have access to. It doesn't appear to show space allocated for directory indexes, and it may miss some other things, but I wouldn't be surprised if the culprit does show up.

Comment: Thanks! I used WizTree instead of WinDirStat and I found that there was a directory which I had not access to, and it contains all of hidden data! Now I'm fixing permissions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 15):

I couldn't edit my comment any longer so I post it as an answer.

I've met once such an incident: It was due to Alternate Data Streams, a feature of NTFS for classic MacOS compatibility in shared folders. Unfortunately this ill-fated feature can be used for malicious purposes. In simple terms, it can be used to fill up your disk but the reserved space cannot be located, as in your case. If you want to check on this, I suggest MS sysinternals tool, [streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams).

Just beware that there are used in some legitimate cases, for example MS SQL server prior to 2014 uses them.

Comment: I did not find any ADS, fortunately! Thanks!

Comment: Alternate data streams are widely used for tainting files downloaded from the Internet (`:Zone.Identifier`), for the new NTFS compression methods in Windows 10, and probably for other purposes. I wouldn't call it an ill-fated feature. The problem is that directory-traversing functions don't return any information about the alternate streams, so you have to open every file to check for them (as far as I know).

Comment: I called them ill-fated because they are not obvious, needing special tools to locate them and thus used for malicious purposes. Also have in mind that on ReFS, MS's new file system, ADS are no longer available. Probably that's why SQL 2014 and newer stopped using them, in order to be able to be installed on ReFS formatted volumes.

Comment: @Krackout alternate data streams were initially not implemented in refs, but they were added later. Ill-fated implies that there was some untimely demise or infamous misuse, which isn't really true

Comment: But there are infamous misuses :) I've faced one in a client of mine. It was a DoS attack, hindering Windows servers by leaving no space left on their disks.

Comment: @Krackout it may just be a matter of semantics, but when I say infamous, I mean prevalent to the point that its misuse outweighs the actual usefulness. This is not something I had even heard of happening before, I had only known about its intended use, which is why I hesitate to call it "infamous". It's more of an edge case in my eyes, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Krackout I believe a better word to use than "ill-fated" would be "ill-conceived."

Comment: Interesting discussion, thanx to my depiction of ADS as "ill-fated"! @PCLuddite, you are right, ADS are now supported in ReFS, I missed that. But fortunately, stream size is limited to 128k only on ReFS, apparently to avoid malicious uses.

Comment: @jayce, probably I preferred ill-fated due to bad personal experience!

Answer (score 7):

The default permissions on `C:\System Volume Information` are `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F`. This means that even when you Run as Administrator you can't normally see files in it. You can use e.g. `psexec` to launch an application under the Local System account, which will then allow WinDirStat et. al. to display everything, or you can use it to add `Administrators` to the ACL. In particular, if you are using Previous Versions then the volume shadow copies are stored within this directory, and these can get quite large.

Answer (score 1):

This was very useful. I've found that Windows Server 2019 has set the default size of the Failover Clustering Diagnostic log to 18014398507384832Kb (!) so server disk was filling up. WinDirStat did not show this .EVTX file but WizTree identified it. Saved the day.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/502994)